# Fatal Error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value [Firebase]

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, option-type

I have looked all over for an answer to my problem but none of the solutions fit. I think its a problem with firebase as I have used breakpoints to see exactly when and where the error was occuring. Everytime it happened when the firebase method ran.

With firebase I am trying to sign a user up using the createUser method. The problem is every time I run this method my app crashes and prints this to the console. I have already checked to make sure my outlets were connected and they werent. However when I connected them I still recieved the problem. What makes this more interesting though is when I print the contents of the variables email and password, it prints out. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class RegisterVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var fName: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var LName: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var Username: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var confirmPassword: UITextField!

     let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()

     //when sign up is tapped
     @IBAction func signUpTapped(_ sender: Any) {

          signUpAction()
     }

     var ref: DatabaseReference!


     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          ref = Database.database().reference()
          self.fName.delegate = self
          self.LName.delegate = self
          self.Username.delegate = self
          self.Email.delegate = self
          self.Password.delegate = self
          self.confirmPassword.delegate = self
     }
     //when return button is pressed ... what should happen
     func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

          fName.resignFirstResponder()
          LName.resignFirstResponder()
          Username.resignFirstResponder()
          Email.resignFirstResponder()
          Password.resignFirstResponder()
          confirmPassword.resignFirstResponder()

          return true
}

     //hides keyboard if you touch view
     override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
          self.view.endEditing(true)
     }


     //function is called from sign up button tapped function

     func signUpAction(){

          guard let email = Email.text, let password = Password.text else{
          print("Something is Happenening")
          return}

          print(email)
          print(password)

          //adds user under the authentication tab on firebase
          firebaseAuth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, err) in

        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
            print(email)
            print(password)
            return  }
        else{
            self.createProfile(user!)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpToMainScene", sender: nil) }
    }
}
```

My indentation may look off as this is practically my first time posting on stack overflow. These are a list of things I have tried:

- Changed parameters to regular strings
- Tried replacing email Email.text! and same with password
- reconnecting outlets however I dont think thats the problem because I can still print the variables
- updated pods to see if there was a new version of firebase

**Error: Fatal Error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value**

Please help me this problem, also I am still relatively new to swift and xcode so please try and explain things as I am still learning a lot of new things. Also ignore the comments, they are there to help me remember what is going on with each function and specific statements.

*My actual code does contain the createProfile function, I just didnt add in this because I thought it was irrelavant*

Comment: What is the error (In the console) ?

Comment: Your code is incomplete since it does not contain the function createProfile

Comment: no it does contain the function I just didnt decide to add it because I thought it was Irreleavant

Comment: What is error line? Does it show error line?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, firebase returns nil value and following function has a block of firebase, which returns optional values for user & error, that you are forcefully unwrapping.

Try this code, and let me know value for `user`.

```
func signUpAction(){

              guard let email = Email.text, let password = Password.text else{
              print("Something is Happenening")
              return}

              print(email)
              print(password)

              //adds user under the authentication tab on firebase
              firebaseAuth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print(err!)
                print(email)
                print(password)
                return  }
            else{ 
                // As per your question, firebase returns nil here
                print("user - \(user)")
                if let userInstance = user {  
                     self.createProfile(userInstance)
                }

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpToMainScene", sender: nil) }
    }
```